# Use a sub query result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table with numbers and dates (1 number each date and dates aren't necessarily at regular intervals).
I would like to get the count of dates when a number isn't in the table.

Where I am :

```
select * 
from 
(   
    select 
    date from nums 
    where chiffre=1 
    order by date desc 
    limit 2
) as f
```

I get this :

```
date
--------------
2014-09-07
--------------
2014-07-26
```

Basically, I have this query dynamically:

```
select * from nums where date between "2014-07-26" and "2014-09-07"
```

And in a second time, browse the whole table (because there I limited to the first 2 rows but I would compare the 2 and 3 and 3 and 4 etc...)

The goal is to get this:

```
date                      |   actual_number_of_real_dates_between_two_given_dates
2014-09-07 - 2014-07-26   |        20
2014-04-02 - 2014-02-12   |        13
```

etc...

How can I do this? Thanks.

Edit:

What I have (just an example, dates and "chiffre" are more complex) :

```
date                      |   chiffre
2014-09-30                |        2
2014-09-29                |        1
2014-09-28                |        2
2014-09-27                |        2
2014-09-26                |        1
2014-09-25                |        2
2014-09-24                |        2
```

etc...

What I need for the number "1":

```
actual_number_of_real_dates_between_two_given_dates
  1
  3
```

etc...

Edit 2:

My updated query thanks to Gordon Linoff

```
select count(n.id) as difference
from nums n inner join
     (select min(date) as d1, max(date) as d2
      from (select date from nums where chiffre=1 order by date desc limit 2) d
     ) dd
where n.date between dd.d1 and dd.d2
```

How can I test row 2 with 3? 3 with 4 etc... Not only last 2?
Should I use a loop? Or I can do it without?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select count(distinct n.date) as numDates,
       (datediff(dd.d2, dd.d1) + 1) as datesInPeriod,
       (datediff(dd.d2, dd.d1) + 1 - count(distinct n.date)) as missingDates
from nums n cross join
     (select date('2014-07-26') as d1, date('2014-09-07') as d2) d
where n.date between dd.d1 and dd.d2;
```

EDIT:

If you just want the last two dates:

```
select count(distinct n.date) as numDates,
       (datediff(dd.d2, dd.d1) + 1) as datesInPeriod,
       (datediff(dd.d2, dd.d1) + 1 - count(distinct n.date)) as missingDates
from nums n cross join
     (select min(date) as d1, max(date) as d2
      from (select date from nums order by date desc limit 2) d
     ) dd
where n.date between dd.d1 and dd.d2;
```

Comment: yes but it's missing the dynamic part
I would like to generate dynamically 2014-07-26 and 2014-09-07
thanks

PS: I only need the "numDates" column ;)

Comment: @sam12 . . . Just add the dates you want into the subquery.  You can even use `union all` and add multiple pairs of dates.

Comment: yep but i don't browse the whole table. I just browse last 2 dates (limit 2)

Comment: I get the 2 dates with a condition (where chiffre=1) but the problem is the limit 2.
I need to browse the whole table (recursive thing or something else)

Comment: I edited and added more information with an example for better understanding